# Relation between the AIC and the Kullback-Leibler Divergence

Tags: aic, kullback-leibler

I am searching a formal derivation of the Akaike Information Criterion from the Kullback-Leibler Divergence.
Can you show me one, or point me toward a book/article in which this is done?

Here I set the notation, but you can use your own if you wish

\begin{equation*}
  KL = E_{\theta_0}(l(\theta_0, Y)) - E_{\theta_0}(l(\theta, Y)) \quad \theta \in \Theta
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  AIC = -2 l(\hat{\theta}, y) + 2p,
\end{equation*}
where

- $Y$ is the random variable which generates the data;
- $\theta_0$ is the true value of the parameter;
- $y$ is a sample;
- $\hat{\theta}$ is the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$ computed using the sample $y$;
- $p$ is the dimension of the parameter space $\Theta$ where $\theta$ belongs.

What I know is that when $\theta \neq \theta_0$, we have that $KL > 0$ (result known as Kullback-Leibler Inequality). So a model is good when $KL$ is low.
Then I know that the first summand of $KL$ is unknown because we do not know $\theta$, but when we want to compare some correctly specified nested models, since it is constant, we can drop it. So I guess that the $AIC$ is a sort of estimate of the second summand of $KL$.

Comment: I am interested too in the answer, please, add some details if you find it.

Comment: In the book "Generalized Additive Models : An Introduction with R" by S. Wood, there is a derivation of the AIC starting from the Kullback-Leibler divergence. See Appendix A.7.

Comment: Here is a blog post containing the derivation you were looking for: https://barumpark.com/blog/2018/aic-and-bic/